# Accord dans « toutes les personnes qui nous ont soutenus »

Tags: grammaire, accord, auxiliaires, participe-passé

Est-ce qu'on écrit « toutes les personnes qui nous ont soutenus » ou bien « toutes les personnes qui nous ont soutenu » ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ça dépend qui est *nous*.

- un ensemble dont le genre d'au moins un élément est masculin: *soutenus*
- un ensemble dont le genre de tous les éléments est féminin: *soutenues*
- un roi: *soutenu*
- une reine: *soutenue*

Comment: Merci beaucoup =D

Comment: Je suppose que l'on ne rencontre pas souvent l'usage avec un roi ou une reine.. :-)

Comment: @ring0 - Je dis _roi_ ou _reine_ parce qu'il s'agit du _nous_ de majesté. Mais ça se trouve souvent--comme j'imagine pour le cas soumis ici--dans des rapports de stage ou des mémoires de thèse.